# How to disable "Most Viewed" Playback on Youtube

Tags: youtube, playback

I dont know where to ask this, but im just ask it here and if you know where im supposed to ask this just let me know.

So a couple days ago when im watching youtube on my pc, a portion of the video always being looping for some reason without me doing anything. The only way to make it stop was to reload the page. Does anyone have the same problem? and how do i disable this?

Heres a pic of what it looks like
[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- Closing out the YouTube application and restarting it?
- Tried opening YouTube with a different browser?
- Updating your computer OS & main browser to the latest version?
- Signed in & out of YouTube?

Try those and see if those work. This is based on my experience in my previous job as an IT Help Desk Specialist. A software feature failed to work, but a simple restart of the browser/computer fixed the issue. In addition, general maintenance usually fixes the issue: updates, security scans, rebooting, deleting unused
files/cache, etc.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer.
But none of it work, yeah it dissapear for a couple video then it happen again on my pc or my mobile phone

Comment: @SukmaQintara consider also check the url of the video - probably it has query params that makes the video to loop in specific range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cant really check it cause it was random, but can you let me know what the url look like that has a query that make the video lopping? So next time it happend i will know it